# Android - Barra de notificação trava ao atualizar o progresso

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza um gerenciador de downloads customizados, estou tentando mostrar uma barra de progresso em uma notificação, porém sempre que entra no laço while não consigo mais descer a barra de notificações e o dispositivo começa a dar umas travadas:

```
private void downloadWithHTTPS(@NonNull URL url){

    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

    try{

        int downloaded = 0;

        File dFile = new File(Uri.parse(getDestPath()).getPath());

        conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        if(conn == null)
            return;

        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);

        FileOutputStream fos;

        if(dFile.exists()){
            conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + dFile.length() + "-");
            downloaded = (int)dFile.length();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dFile, true);
        }else{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dFile);
        }

        conn.connect();

        processResponse(conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage());

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);

        Log.i("Downloader", "Total file length: " + conn.getContentLength());

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int pos = 0;

        while((pos = bis.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0){

            downloaded += pos;

            bos.write(data, 0, pos);
            mNotification.setContentText("Baixando " + downloaded / 100 + "%");
            mNotification.setProgress(downloaded, pos, false);
            mNotManager.notify(NOTIFICATIONS_ID, mNotification.build());
        }

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        bis.close();


        mNotification.setContentText("Baixado");
        mNotification.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotManager.notify(NOTIFICATIONS_ID, mNotification.build());

    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Downloader", "Could not download file: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        if(conn != null)
            conn.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: Tentou criar uma thread ou `doInBackground`? Veja: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Usei uma thread e o sleep por 5000 milissegundos, porém da um erro indicando que o InputStream foi fechado

Comment: Mas ai já é "outro" erro, sem log detalhado fica um pouco complicado

Comment: Ao ler as documentações das Notificações encontrei a causa do meu erro, https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification, ao atualizar muito frequentemente as notificações o sistema pode travar, uma solução seria realmente o thread porém criar um intervalo para o laço while

Answer (score 0):

A minha solução foi a seguinte:

```
package com.samuelives.videoplayer.downloader;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

import com.samuelives.videoplayer.R;
import com.samuelives.videoplayer.util.StorageHelper;
import com.samuelives.videoplayer.util.Web;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class Downloader extends IntentService{

    public static final String TARGET_URL = "target_url";
    public static final String TARGET_TITLE = "target_title";

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 30101998;

    private String title, mURL;

    private int downloaded = 0;

    public Downloader() {
        super("IVP_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        title = intent.getStringExtra(TARGET_TITLE);
        mURL = intent.getStringExtra(TARGET_URL);

        try {

            URL url = new URL(mURL);
            download(url);

        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e("Downloader", "Falha ao criar a URL: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private void download(final URL url){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            HttpURLConnection conn;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try{

                    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", Web.getUserAgent(Downloader.this));

                    FileOutputStream fos;

                    File dFile = new File(Uri.parse(getDestPath()).getPath());
                    if(!dFile.exists()){
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(dFile);
                    }else{
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + dFile.length() + "-");
                        downloaded = (int)dFile.length();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(dFile, true);
                    }

                    conn.connect();

                    if(processResponse(conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage())) {

                        int totalSize = conn.getContentLength();

                        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Downloader.this, "IVP_NOTIFICATION_CHANEL")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_download)
                                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dm_downloading_msg))
                                .setContentText(title)
                                .setProgress(totalSize, 0, false)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_PROGRESS)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());

                        bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);

                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        int pos = 0;

                        synchronized(this){

                            while ((pos = bis.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {

                                downloaded += pos;

                                bos.write(data, 0, pos);
                                Thread.sleep(1000);

                                Log.d("Downloader", "Baixados: " + 100 * downloaded / totalSize + "% .");

                                notification.setProgress(totalSize, downloaded, false);
                                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
                            }

                        }

                        notification.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
                    }

                }catch (IOException | InterruptedException e){
                    Log.e("Downloader", "Falha ao baixar o arquivo: " + e.getMessage());
                }finally {

                    if(conn != null)
                        conn.disconnect();

                    try{

                        if(bis != null)
                            bis.close();

                        if(bos != null){
                            bos.flush();
                            bos.close();
                        }

                    }catch (IOException e){
                        Log.e("Downloader", "Falha ao encerrar os buffers: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }

            }

        }).start();

    }

    private String getDestPath(){

        String destPath = null;

        if(StorageHelper.haveSdCard(this)){

            File storageDir = StorageHelper.getStorage(this);
            if(!storageDir.exists()){
                storageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            Log.i("Downloader", "Download path: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());

            destPath = new File(storageDir.getPath(), title + "." + MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mURL)).getAbsolutePath();

            Log.i("Downloader", "Dest file: " + destPath);

        }else{

            destPath = new File(StorageHelper.getInternalStorage(this), title + "." +MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mURL)).getAbsolutePath();

            Log.i("Downloader", "Dest file: " + destPath);

        }

        return destPath;
    }

    private boolean processResponse(int code, String message){

        boolean ok = true;

        switch(code){

            case 405:
                Log.e("Downloader", "Response code: " + code + " "+ message);
                ok = false;
                break;

            default:
                Log.d("Downloader", "Response code: " + code + " " + message);
                break;

        }

        return ok;
    }

}
```

Como lido na documentação da notificação, atualizar muito frequentemente a notificação pode levar a travamentos do sistema, então adicionei pequenos intervalos e o problema foi resolvido.